# AdMob API POST connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, admob

I would create an App for keep my AdMob revenue on my iPhone. I've read [API Documentation](http://mm.admob.com/web/pdf/AdMob_API_Documentation.pdf) and wrote some code. BUT I have problem with POST request that give me a null request.response!!

```
NSString* PostURL= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.admob.com/v2/auth/login"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:PostURL]];
[request setPostValue:APIKey forKey:@"client_key"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;"];
[request setPostValue:@"mymail@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"];
[request setPostValue:@"mypassword" forKey:@"password"];


[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];
```

And fetch response using ASIHTTPRequestDelegate method:

```
-(void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

NSLog(@"didReceive data %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);}
```

The output is the same:
 didReceive data: (null)

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The REST API seems no longer exist for new Admob web.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing an application, you'll need to use the native [Google AdMob Ads SDK](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/), not an API, to get ads.

Check out the getting started guide [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ios/fundamentals).

Comment: I think you misread the OP's question. He wants to track his AdMob *revenue* in an app--not display AdMob ads in an app. For that, he needs the API.

Comment: Thank you guys, as @Matt says i would make an app to track my Admob revenue! Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use ASIFormDataRequest for this call. You should use the standard ASIHTTPRequest class instead and set its method to POST. Then, you pass the parameters not as header fields, but rather as the body of the request. So your code should be something like this:

```
NSString *bodyString = @"client_key=123456&email=email@gmail.com&password=password";

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.admob.com/v2/auth/login"]];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request setPostBody:[bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

You can also try explicitly setting your Content-Type header to 'application/json'. JSON appears to be what comes back when you do a POST to the url.

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
```

You can also try to use curl from the command line to see what it's sending if you want to troubleshoot the raw request. Use a command like:

```
> curl -d "client_key=123456&email=email@gmail.com&password=password" https://api.admob.com/v2/auth/login
```

Best Regards.

Comment: Really helpful, as soon as possible i'll try tris way and share with you tue result...really thank you! Cordially, Luca